# regex to match the string more than one time

Tags: java, regex

I have a string as follows

```
"SampleFilter('x','y','z') AND TestFilter('a','b','c') AND SampleFilter('d','e','f')"
```

Here I want a regex to match the occurrence of SampleFilter so i want output to return all the occurrence of SampleFilter

I have tried below pattern

```
".*SampleFilter\\((.*?)\\).*"
```

But I have captured group 1 and it is returning only last occurrence

Comment: Please show us your attempts.

Comment: `SampleFilter\\((.*?)\\)` works fine as can be seen [here](https://regex101.com/r/XSLJiL/2)

Comment: Remove `.*` from both sides of your regex.

Comment: I am using this pattern in java and when I removed .* from regex it matches only first match

Comment: You will need to iterate

Comment: iterate what? when I capture group 0 it is returning like SampleFilter('x','y','z') AND SampleFilter('d','e','f'). If group 1 it is returning only 'd','e','f'

Comment: @wazza see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't retrieve your data with a simple match; you need to iterate:

```
    String text = "SampleFilter('x','y','z') AND TestFilter('a','b','c')"
            + " AND SampleFilter('d','e','f')";
    Pattern re = Pattern.compile("SampleFilter\\((.*?)\\)");
    Matcher matcher = re.matcher(text);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
```